# create nav dropdown with bootstrap twitter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i started learn using bootstrap twitter,  [Bootstrap_dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) . but i donk know why my coding doesnt like that..

this is my coding for try dropdown..

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />


<script type="text/javascript">  


                $(document).ready(function () 
                {  
                    $('.dropdown-tonggle').dropdown();  
                });  
</script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body background="img/vlcsnap-2013-12-23-14h06m41s77.png">
    <div class="navbar">
                  <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                      <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                  <a data-tonggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-tonggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">2-level Dropdown <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    </div>

                </body>

    </html>
```

why the result like this?

[image]

and i already have this file where i get it from getbootstrap.com

### bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js dropdown.js jquery-2.1.0.js bootstrap.css bootstrap.min.css bootstrap-responsive.css bootstrap-responsive.min.css

Comment: You have a typo `<a data-tonggle="dropdown">`, it says to**n**ggle. That's probably the problem.

Comment: <a data-tonggle="dropdown">Language</a> but i already type it in this line

Comment: It says tonggle, is toggle. BTW, you have one `<li>` and three `<a>` inside. If you want three levels, you need to put each `<a>` inside a `<li>`

Comment: oh yes...but it doesnot work too..thanks for helping :D

Comment: The `class="dropdown-toggle"` is missing in the `<a>`, it should be `<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">`.

Comment: oh...i still dont know how it works...i just want two levels..can you help me and give me the correct answers? i want it just like this page [link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

Comment: i already edit my post..i edit toggle to tonggle

Comment: Is the other way around, it should be toggle. And try to update the jQuery library, at least 1.9.0.

Comment: @azeós where?<a data-tonggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-tonggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>  is this right??

Comment: No, it is: `<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>` [Bootstrap 3 navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: @azeós i already update it to jQuery 2.1.0.js

Comment: You shouldn't need to declare anything with Javascript if you're using the data attributes. Most of Bootstrap works without custom scripting.